# Running python program on linux

Tags: python, linux, mapreduce, inverted-index

I'm not very familiar with linux as well as python. I'm taking this class that have example code of a inverted index program on python. I would like to know how to run and test the code. Here's the code that was provided to me.

This is the code for the mapping file. (inverted_index_map.py)

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    #print(line)
    key, value = line.split('\t', 1)
    for word in value.strip().split():
        if len(word) <=5 and len(word) >= 3:
          print '%s\t%s' % (word, key.split(':', 1)[0]) #what are we emitting?
```

This is the code for the reduce program. (inverted_index_reduce.py)

```
import sys
key   = None
total = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    k, v  = line.split('\t', 1)

    if key == k:
        total += v.strip() #what are we accumulating?
    else:
        if key:
            print '%s\t%s' % (key, total) #what are we printing?
        key   = k
        total = v

if key:
    print '%s\t%s' % (key, total) #what are we printing?
```

It wasn't an executable file so I tried

```
chmod +x inverted_index_map.py
```

Then I tried to run the program with:

```
./inverted_index_map.py testfilename.txt
```

But I'm not sure if the program is waiting for some kind of input from the keyboard or something. So my question is how do I test this code and see the result? I'm really not familiar with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two programs are written as command-line tools, meaning they take their input from the stdin and display it to stdout. By default, that means that they take input from the keyboard and display output on the screen. In most Linux shells, you can change where input comes from and output goes to by using `<file.txt` to get input from `file.txt`  and `>file.txt` to write output in `file.txt`. Additionally, you can make the output of one command become the input of another command by using `firstcommand | secondcommand`.

Another problem is that the scripts you posted don't have a `#!` (shebang) line, which means that you will need to use `python inverted_index_map.py` to run your programs.

If you want to run `inverted_index_map.py` with input from `testfilename.txt` and see the output on the screen, you should try running:

```
python inverted_index_map.py <testfilename.txt
```

To run `inverted_index_map.py` followed by `inverted_index_reduce.py` with input from `testfilename.txt` and output written to `outputfile.txt`, you should try running:

```
python inverted_index_map.py <testfilename.txt | python inverted_index_reduce.py >outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inverted_index_map.py", line 6, in <module>
    key, value = line.split('\t', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
I got this error when I try to run the command that you gave.

Comment: This is now a problem of debugging the python program. You can put the line `sys.stderr.write(repr(line))` above the line giving the error to see exactly what is on the line (without contaminating sys.stdout), or `sys.stderr.write(str(line.split('\t', 1)))` to see what you are trying to split into.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run the script using the `python` command to invoke the python interpreter and pass the path to your script as an argument. Check out this article, I think it will help get you started:

http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/

Comment: so what is the different between using ./ and using the python command?

Comment: This is missing the question of "*if the program is waiting for some kind of input from the keyboard or something*"

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the file in as standard input like so

```
python inverted_index_map.py < testfilename.txt
```

or prefix the python file with `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` then `chmod +x` it and you can run

```
.\inverted_index_map.py < testfilename.txt
```

Or

```
cat testfilename.txt | ./inverted_index_map.py
```

Which is what [Writing an Hadoop MapReduce Program in Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) recommends.